# PL/SQL value_error exception not getting caught

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql

This is my Department table:

```
create table Department(
    DeptNo int primary key, 
    DeptName varchar2(21) not null, 
    DeptLocation varchar2(13) not null
);
```

I am trying to insert value for DeptName column with length more than accepted i.e. 21, which means I should get "VALUE_ERROR" exception.
The plsql code I am running is:

```
begin
    insert into department values(1, 'Some random department name', 'SomeLocation');
exception
    when value_error then
        dbms_output.put_line('Cannot store the value!');
end;
```

As I am trying to catch the exception, it is not getting caught. I am getting the error:

> ORA-12899: value too large for column "SQL_ZIRHWMLFPCEAKPGYGJJZLSIFI"."DEPARTMENT"."DEPTNAME" (actual: 27, maximum: 21) ORA-06512: at line 2
>   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

But if I change my exception from "value_error" to "others"

```
begin
    insert into department values(1, 'Some random department name', 'SomeLocation');
exception
    when others then
        dbms_output.put_line('Cannot store the value!');
end;
```

then I get the expected output

> Cannot store the value!

Where could I have gone wrong? Please let me know. Thanks!

PS: I am running all the code on livesql.oracle.com

Comment: If you are downvoting a question, please leave a comment mentioning why you are doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, what you are using is correct and it should had worked as desired. But the exception `VALUE_ERROR` behaves differently in somecases. See the below illustrative example.

> As per the documentation value_error comes when there is an
>   arithmetic, conversion, truncation, or size-constraint error occurs.
>   For example, when your program selects a column value into a character
>   variable, if the value is longer than the declared length of the
>   variable, PL/SQL aborts the assignment and raises VALUE_ERROR. In
>   procedural statements, VALUE_ERROR is raised if the conversion of a
>   character string into a number fails.

The last line says, *In procedural statements, VALUE_ERROR is raised if the conversion of a character string into a number fails.*, but when i run this in a block it rasied INVALID_NUMBER exception.

```
SQL> declare
  2    n number;
  3  begin
  4    select to_number('a')
  5      into n
  6      from dual
  7    ;
  8  exception
  9    when value_error
 10    then
 11      dbms_output.put_line ('Value Error');
 12    when invalid_number
 13    then
 14      dbms_output.put_line ('Invalid Number');
 15  end;
 16  /
Invalid Number

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

I expected that it would raise the VALUE_ERROR but it didn't. So it might be the case that Oracle was not able to raise value_error in your case and when you used `WHEN OTHERS` it was caught.

Edit:

> Ok. So is it possible somehow to catch value_error exception by giving
>   the value longer than the declared length of the variable?

**Explicit Raise of System Exception** : Not very elegant but you can do it as below.

```
declare

var int;
var1 varchar2(21);
var2 varchar2(13);

begin

var1:='Some random department name';
var2:= 'SomeLocation'

If var1 > 21 then
 RAISE VALUE_ERROR; 
END IF; 

If var2 > 13 then
 RAISE VALUE_ERROR; 
END IF; 

insert into department values(1, var1, var2);

exception
    when value_error  then
        dbms_output.put_line('Cannot store the value!');
end;
```

Comment: Ok. So is it possible somehow to catch value_error exception by giving the  value longer than the declared length of the variable?

Comment: You can use length to check the variable length and if its more that the specified limit then raised VALUE_ERROR.

Comment: I tried the code in the edit section of your answer. The line `var1:='Some random department name';` itself raises the value_error which means I did not even have to check if var1 > 21. So that worked! Thanks. +1 for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

VALUE_ERROR was not the exception raised when you ran your code, if you want, you can defined an EXCEPTION and catch it, see below code for sample,

```
DECLARE
   ORA_12899 EXCEPTION;
   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(ORA_12899, -12899);
begin
    insert into department values(1, 'Some random department name', 'SomeLocation');
exception
    when ORA_12899 then
        dbms_output.put_line('Cannot store the value!');
end;
/
```

Below code will have a VALUE_ERROR;

```
DECLARE
   ORA_12899 EXCEPTION;
   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(ORA_12899, -12899);
   v_dept VARCHAR2(20);
begin
    v_dept := 'Some random department name';
    insert into department values(1, v_dept, 'SomeLocation');
exception
    when ORA_12899 then
        dbms_output.put_line('Cannot store the value!');
end;
/
```

Comment: This works. But can you tell me why value_error was not the exception raised despite it being the exception that should have been raised according to the docs?

Comment: ORA-12899 - is raised when you put (this could be in INSERT/UPDATE/MERGE statements ) a text to a column but the length of the text is greater than the data length of the column.

VALUE_ERROR - see the other answer of this question as it has a larger explanation.

In your code, it would be ORA-12899 as you are putting a value in a column, but if you had DECLARE a variable and assigned a value that has a length greater than 20, then VALUE_ERROR will be raised, see my updated answer